# Convert char in char array to its own char array in ANSI C

Tags: c, arrays, character

I have a char array representing a double precision floating point number in hex form.

```
char *hex = ""402499999999999A"
```

I want to extract each char in `hex` as its own char array and read it into an unsigned int `num`. For example, I tried

```
sscanf((char *)&hex[3], "%X", &num);
```

But this doesn't give me the 4th char as an individual char array, it gives me the sub char array from the 4th position on, which I suppose is because arrays are given by the pointer of their first element.

Is there a better way to do this? I looked at `strcpy` and it seems that I can only copy the first n chars, so that's no good.

Comment: Can you please refine your question? I'm confused as to what you mean by individual char array versus sub char array. A string is an array of char and indexing an element will give you that one element, however I see you're taking the address of that which will just give you a pointer to that element. What exactly do you want to accomplish.

Comment: Well, a char array is identified by a (const) pointer to its first element, right? So by doing (char *)&hex[3] I am getting the pointer of the fourth element of the char array `hex`. I had thought that this would give me the fourth char as an individual char array, but instead this gives me the sub char array `hex[4 to end]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in many ways. One way is as follows (which is the correct way of how *you* were doing it):

```
char only_1_char[2] = {'\0', '\0'};
only_1_char[0] = hex[3];
sscanf(only_1_char, "%X", &num);
```

and a more efficient solution:

```
if (hex[3] <= '9')
    num = hex[3] - '0';
else
    num = hex[3] - 'A' + 10;
```

This is just a sample, though. In truth you need to take care of invalid input and lower cases if that is a possibility.

Comment: Ok, this works. Is there a way to use the first method, i.e. `sscanf`, and avoid having to use the temporary variable `only_1_char`?

Comment: `sscanf` needs a `NUL`-terminated string. You would need an extra variable anyways. One other method is: `char temp = hex[i+1]; hex[i+1] = '\0'; sscanf(&hex[i], "%X", &num); hex[i+1] = temp;` but it still uses the temporary variable.

Comment: If you know the length of the string (in `length`), then there is an extremely ugly way to do it without an extra variable: `#define SWAP(x, y) do { x = x^y; y = x^y; x = x^y; } while (0)` and later `SWAP(hex[i], hex[length-1]); sscanf(&hex[length-1], "%X", &num); SWAP(hex[i], hex[length-1]);` You should note that this won't work for `i = length-1`. Like I said, this is a terrible method (just wanted to let you know it _is_ possible).

Comment: Indeed, both methods I mentioned in the comments give you an _undefined behavior_ with your example because you are working with a pointer to a string literal (which shouldn't be overwritten) rather than an array of chars. Like I said, the most efficient way for you would be the `if-else` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for(i = 0; src[i] != 0; i++) {
    if(src[i]) <= '9') {
        dest[i] = src[i] - '0';
    } else {
        dest[i] = toupper(src[i]) - 'A' + 10;
    }
}
```

It can be improved with error handling (e.g. detect if "src[i]" contains a valid/sane character).